# Mostrar pedido a base de datos exceptuando un elemento en especifico con laravel

Tags: laravel

necesito hacer una consulta a la base de datos, tengo esta linea pero quisiera exceptuar la categoría de id 1:

estaba intentando algo así:

$categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->**except('id', '1')**->paginate();

Gracias

Comment: prueba con `->where('id', '<>', '1')->paginate()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Genial!! me sirve

Comment: O indicando que el id sea mayor a 1 as{i: **$categories = Category::where('id', '>', 1)orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escribo los comentarios en una respuesta solo para cerrar la pregunta.

Puedes filtrar el resultado de la consulta con cláusulas [where()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses).

- Indicando que la propiedad 'id' se distinta de un valor dado:

```php
$categories = Category::where('id', '<>', '1')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate();
```

- Del comentario de @Aprendiz:

  > O indicando que el 'id' sea mayor a 1 así:

```php
$categories = Category::where('id', '>', 1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate();
```